# Were shaggy dog stories known before they got that name?

Tags: folklore

A shaggy dog story is a lengthy anecdote that induces an expectation of a surprising, amusing or otherwise memorable conclusion but which ends instead with a punchline that is utterly mundane or even irrelevant to what has just been narrated.

Were there any such stories before they got that name, whenever that might have been?

Comment: Very interesting question!  In some ways a Lit question, but here I think the intent is determining if there are potential folkloric roots.

Comment: I've only ever encountered them as a type of orally transmitted anecdote. It's always struck me as a strange genre - I don't find them amusing at all. But others' taste may differ :-)